# Why do most people use Drivers instead of other Observables in MVVM?

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I've seen several codes of MVVM structure, most of which are Driver in Driver out.
Why do most codes in ViewModel use Driver when they don't have to run on Main Thread?
Isn't it only necessary to run on the main thread when processing UI logic on the View Controller? I don't know why ViewModel codes should be executed on Main Thread. And since it is inconvenient to mix Signal and Driver together, do other people treat all events as drivers? In my case, I can't merge Signal and Driver, so I can't use them together

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: https://github.com/sergdort/CleanArchitectureRxSwift/blob/master/CleanArchitectureRxSwift/Scenes/AllPosts/PostsViewModel.swift This is the code that I referred to.

Comment: That's a good point. I personally used this approach in the past and then decided to move to Observable in Observable out mostly because if you use Driver you will have to import RxCocoa in your VM and RxCocoa depends on UIKit and this leaks View layer aspects inside the VM. Some people don't consider this an issue but I think that having this separation really helps. If you go with this route then VM can run its logic on a separate thread and View needs to take into account that outputs might be sent on a non main thread.